# Error when getting column values of a Pandas dataframe after doing row sums

Tags: python, pandas

For this dataframe:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(1,9,10), 'b':np.random.randint(1,9,10)})
```

I am trying to create a new columns by doing sum of each row:

```
t['sum'] = t.sum(axis=1)
```

but, when I try to retrieve the values by:
t.sum.values
I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'

However, if I just sum the two columns manually
t['sum2'] = t.a + t.b
I can then get the column value by t.sum2.values without error. Can somebody explain to me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Cause `sum` is build in function for pandas

You should call the columns with

```
t['sum'].values
```

Rather than

```
t.sum.values#(wrong)
```